# android sdk manager not updating

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, android-sdk-manager

While trying to update my eclipse sdk manger for android I'm getting the following error instead of updating:

```
Downloading Android SDK Platform-tools, revision 20
URL not found: C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\temp\platform-tools_r20-windows.zip (Access is denied)
Downloading Documentation for Android SDK, API 19, revision 2
URL not found: C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\temp\docs-19_r02.zip (Access is denied)
Downloading SDK Platform Android 4.4.2, API 19, revision 3
URL not found: C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\temp\android-19_r03.zip (Access is denied)
Downloading SDK Platform Android 4.3, API 18, revision 2
URL not found: C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\temp\android-18_r02.zip (Access is denied)
Downloading Samples for SDK API 19, revision 5
URL not found: C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\temp\samples-19_r05.zip (Access is denied)
Downloading Sources for Android SDK, API 19, revision 2
URL not found: C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\temp\sources-19_r02.zip (Access is denied)
Skipping 'Android SDK Tools, revision 23'; it depends on 'Android SDK Platform-tools, revision 20' which was not installed.
Done. Nothing was installed.
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The error is `Access is denied` which means that you should run the SDK Manager as an Administrator to have full access on `C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk`.

You must locate your `android.bat` and do this:

[image]

Comment: This is the right solution. The second solution is to move Eclipse and the Android SDK outside of the Program Files/ which is a protected folder in Windows.

Answer (score 1):

better yet, do this on windows 7, sam as the answer from ylecuyer but more visual

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There will be possibility of having proxy problem on your internet connection if that was not a problem  then 
you should try to run your sdk manager exe as administrator mode to fixed the problem. if that alo no t worked then you can dowload the zip of adt update install through local path.

In most of case while updating the adt in eclipse it can corrupt your plugin in that case you have to change eclipse and have to do fresh installation with latest adt.