# Cordova : [Error: Please install Android target: "android-21"

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, android-sdk-tools

I just updated cordova + ionic in my app, after that i installed successfully Android-SDK v22 via Android SDK manager.

But after the running command:

```
cordova build android
```

I always get the following message:

```
Running command: /Users/peter/workspace/myapp/platforms/android/cordova/build 
[Error: Please install Android target: "android-21".

Hint: Open the SDK manager by running: /Users/peter/adt-bundle-mac/sdk/tools/android
You will require:
1. "SDK Platform" for android-21
2. "Android SDK Platform-tools (latest)
3. "Android SDK Build-tools" (latest)]
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: /Users/peter/workspace/myapp/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 2
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
Error: /Users/peter/workspace/myapp/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 2
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:131:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:1008:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1080:5)
```

I tried also

```
cordova platform rm android 
cordova platform add android
```

But with the same result:

I tried to find a few hours any working solution, but with luck.

Thanks for any advice.

System information:

```
OS: Mac OS X Yosemite
Node Version: v0.12.0
Cordova CLI: 4.3.0
Ionic Version: 0.9.27
Ionic CLI Version: 1.3.18
Xcode version: Xcode 6.2 Build version 6C131e 
ios-sim version: 3.1.1 
ios-deploy version: 1.4.0
```

Comment: Does sdk-21 show in `android list targets` ?

Comment: if it's asking for android-21, you need to install android-21. Installing 22 wouldn't satisfy the requirement for 21.

Comment: I assume he doesn't wants to use 21. Using ionic like in my case, you just "start" a boilerplate project, which pre-configures 21, without asking you.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

I just had the same problem.
I had to change the target:

```
# Project target.
target=android-22
```

This should be done in two files:

*myApp*/platforms/android/**project.properties**
*myApp*/platforms/android/CordovaLib/**project.properties**

Also the manifest should be updated:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="22" />
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. Just want to add this: even though in project.properties, it says everything will be overridden blah blah, just edit it and it will work.

Comment: I wrote "android" on command line to see my installed version which is 23, so I changed 22 in these files to 23

Comment: i have all these settings but still getting the same error message. what exactly do i need to change in those files ?

Comment: Which Android-Version have you installed in your SDK? If you have another version installed than *22*, you have to edit the files correspondingly.

Comment: See the name of plateform in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platforms`.

Answer (score 26):

Follow these steps.
1) Type `android` on command line.(Make sure ANDROID_HOME and PATH are set properly)
2) Select `API 21` from the populated list.
3) Click `install packages`.
4) Type `android avd` on command line.
5) Set API level and other config.
6) Now type `ionic build android`.

Comment: Thanks, the PATH had a reference to an old android sdk's - that was the case for me

Answer (score 11):

many times the problem is that not is configurated the path environment variable ANDRIOD_HOME.
Take a look

```
%ANDROID_HOME% = C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk
In Path:
%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;
%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools;
```

Comment: This works for me. Try to add all of this to System Environment Variables!

Answer (score 3):

In my case it was the path to my SDK folder that was causing this error.

C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk

changed to

C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\sdk

Comment: OutlawBruce, thanks a lot. This is the ideal solution

Answer (score 1):

I have been having the same problem in windows. It appeared that when I was running the SDK Manager you have to select "Run as Administrator" otherwise it denies permission to install certain files, on of them being "ANDROID-22"

Here is the the link I found to resolve this issue:
[android sdk manger not updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25074584/android-sdk-manger-not-updating)

Answer (score 1):

Open Android SDK Manager, and check whether the target version exists, Install if not exists.

Answer (score 0):

**Make sure your project path doesn't consist spaces.**

I face the same problem asking me to install the target android platform when build. I have triple confirm my android sdk path, jdk path and various setting in path but still getting the same error. Finally, the problem resolved by simply renamed(removed spaces) the folder that store my Cordova project. For example : "C:\Cordova & Phonegap Sample\MyCordovaApp" to "C:\Cordova_Sample\MyCordova".

Answer (score 0):

another way to fulfill an android target requirement would be:

```
$sdkmanager "platforms;android-21"
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who run Visual Studio and have Mobile Development with JavaScript installed,
you can run `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\AndroidSDK\25\tools\android.BAT` and then proceed to install Android 5.0.1 or the relevant API.

[image]