# How to build Android application in Cordova?

Tags: android, cordova

I use Cordova for building an Android application. When I execute `cordova build android --release` command this error is displayed:

> Error: please install Android target: "android-22"

My target lists: 
8, 15 and 19

When I change `target` to `android-19` or `android-15` (in \platforms\android\project.properties) and execute `cordova build android --release` this error is displayed:

> Exception failed for task :CordovaLib:compileRelease/java. And an error in \platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:126 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to SDK manager and install the latest version of Android.

[image]

And make sure you are also using the latest version of the Android SDK tools. If you've already done these, take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29396252/cordova-error-please-install-android-target-android-21)

Comment: If I want to build my project on target 15 , I should install Android 5.1.1(API 22) ?

Comment: My android SDK tools is 24.0.2

Comment: Yes, you have to install the latest even if you want to build your app to target 15. Also, the latest SDK tools as at this morning is 24.3.1