# Error: Please install Android target: "android-22" when SDK manager shows it is installed

Tags: android, windows, cordova

I have the android-22 installed on my environmet. But still when running the cordova build android getting the following error:

> C:\Work\WebRTC\FirstResponder\rtcommmobile>cordova build android
>   Running command: C:\Work\WebRTC\nodejs\node.exe C:\Work\WebRTC\FirstResponder\rtcommmobile\hooks\after_prepare\
>   add to body class: platform-android
>   Running command: C:\Work\WebRTC\nodejs\node.exe C:\Work\WebRTC\FirstResponder\rtcommmobile\hooks\after_prepare\
>   Running command: cmd "/s /c "C:\Work\WebRTC\FirstResponder\rtcommmobile\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat""
>   [Error: Please install Android target: "android-22".
>
> Hint: Open the SDK manager by running: C:\Work\WebRTC\android\android-sdk\tools\android.BAT
>   You will require:
>   1. "SDK Platform" for android-22
>   2. "Android SDK Platform-tools (latest)
>   3. "Android SDK Build-tools" (latest)]
>   ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 2
>   You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
>   Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 2
>       at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\anatf\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\
>       at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
>       at maybeClose (child_process.js:766:16)
>       at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:833:5)

My system information is:

> Running on Windows
>
> Cordova CLI: 5.1.1
>   Ionic Version: 1.0.0-beta.14
>   Ionic CLI Version: 1.6.1
>   Ionic App Lib Version: 0.3.3
>   OS: Windows 7 SP1
>   Node Version: v0.10.35
>
> Installed platforms: android 4.0.0, browser 3.5.2, ios 3.8.0
>   Available platforms: amazon-fireos, blackberry10, firefoxos, windows, windows8, wp8
>
> Available Android targets:
>
> id: 1 or "android-22"
>        Name: Android 5.1.1
>        Type: Platform
>        API level: 22
>        Revision: 2
>        Skins: HVGA, QVGA, WQVGA400, WQVGA432, WSVGA, WVGA800 (default), WVGA854, WXGA720, WXGA800, WXGA800-7in, AndroidWearRound, AndroidWearRound400x400, AndroidWearRoundChin320x290, AndroidWearSquare,
>    AndroidWearSquare320x320, AndroidWearRound, AndroidWearRound400x400, AndroidWearRoundChin320x290, AndroidWearSquare, AndroidWearSquare320x320
>    Tag/ABIs : android-tv/armeabi-v7a, android-tv/x86, android-wear/armeabi-v7a, android-wear/x86, default/armeabi-v7a, default/x86, default/x86_64

Anyone can help me ?

Comment: Probably there are two different SDKs. Or you haven't installed SDK platform. Follow the instruction 'Open the SDK manager by running: C:\Work\WebRTC\android\android-sdk\tools\android.BAT You will require: 1. "SDK Platform" for android-22 2.' and make sure it is installed.

Answer (score 1):

As it was commented, there could be 2 different sdk's. Take a look at the c:/Users//android-sdks and c:/Users//AppData/Local/Android/android-sdks.

From what I can tell its referencing either of these and the one its referencing is missing the required files. Trying copying them across.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check targetSdkVersion and minSdkVersion in project.properties files. You can find the full solution by going to the Sebastian G. Marinescu's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29552295/1666800)