# Ionic not building android due to android-24 target

Tags: android, sdk, ionic-framework

I am doing the following ionic command:

```
ionic build android
```

I am receiving this error message:

```
Hint: Open the SDK manager by running: /usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/24.3.4/bin/android
You will require:
1. "SDK Platform" for android-24
2. "Android SDK Platform-tools (latest)
3. "Android SDK Build-tools" (latest)]
```

So I opened the SDK manager and I see the following info:
[image]

I have removed, added, installed, trying to build, etc. But I have had zero luck. I have also tried all of [these changes to my files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29396252/cordova-error-please-install-android-target-android-21). But still nothing.

I have also tried adding the android_home path to my .bash_profile. I currently do not have it configured. But it didn't work earlier.

Comment: Please try to install every tools?

Answer (score 1):

Instruction 1:

After adding your `ANDROID_HOME`, make sure you do the below:

1. Restart your System or run source ~/.bash_profile
2. Remove Android platform from your project ionic cordova platform rm android or ionic platform rm android
3. Add Android platform ionic cordova platform add android
4. Then ionic cordova run android or ionic run android

Instruction 2:

To set your `ANDROID_HOME` and `JAVA_HOME`, follow the below steps:

1. Run command open ~/.bash_profile
2. Paste the below in the file that opens on your Text editor

   ```
   export ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/24.4.1_1
   export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
   ```
3. Save  -  "Command S" or "Ctrl S"
4. Then Follow the "Instruction 1:" above

**NOTE: Make sure you have 24.4.1_1 SDK**

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why it mentions `android-24`, but for me just installing the latest (in this case `23`) and updating both project.properties files and the manifest as explained in the SO link you menioned ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29552295/188926) answer) worked.