# Change Android SDK version in Visual Studio 2015 Apache Cordova mobile application via User Interface

Tags: android, cordova, visual-studio-2015, apache-cordova

How can we change the android sdk version using UI in visual studio 2015 apache cordova mobile application?

I know that there is a way to change this version via project.properties files inside platforms/android folder in project, but I am searching for a way to change them via user interface.(I am also aware of links such as [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29396252/cordova-error-please-install-android-target-android-21) in stackoverflow, but these are not my answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We do not currently expose this setting in the config designer. The tools will use whatever version is pinned to the CLI version you're targeting. The best way to change this is to do Cordova platform add from the command line and specify a different version than what you're CLI version is targeting.

(Disclosure: I work on the tools for Apache Cordova in visual studio at Microsoft)